# upload Image into database from Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I try to upload an image with this code and everything is ok.

```html
onAvatarSelected(event) {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    this.tmp = "tmp";
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("image", this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.http
      .post(this.authservice.getSubDomain() + "/upload", fd)
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log("res",'../../assets/images/directeur/'+res);
        this.icone = res;
        this.pathAvatarSuper = res;

      });
  }
 
}
```

and in my HtML

```html
<div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-12 top_br ">
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">Icône</div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">

    <div class="Dr_icon_MD" [style.background-image]="icone!=''?('url('+ icone+')'):('url(../../assets/images/directeur/avatar.png)')  "  >
      <input autocomplete="off" class="file_input_Dr" type="file"
             name="input-file-preview" (change)="onAvatarSelected($event)"  #fileInput />
    </div>  
    
  </div>

</div>
```

My problem is I can't see the image when I select the file:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojoSM.jpg)

Comment: You mean you want a thumbnail of the image you upload ?

Comment: yes this is it :)

Comment: how the server returns image? string base64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you get the image from the server.

```
this.http
  .post(this.authservice.getSubDomain() + "/upload", fd)
  .subscribe(res => {
    console.log("res",'../../assets/images/directeur/'+res);
    this.createImage(res);
  }, error => {
    //set icone to default avatar
  }););
```

Next, you read your image

```
createImage(image: Blob) {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
      this.icone = reader.result;
   }, false);

   if (icone) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(image);
   }
}
```

Then,

```
<div class="Dr_icon_MD" [style.background-image]="icone">
```

Comment: @darinedarine glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try to add css to your div.Dr_icon_MD element.

```
div.Dr_icon_MD{
    height: 5rem;
    width: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: can you make a plunkr with angular and html ?